# Getting log entry "disk online" from system log

Tags: shell, parsing, logging, awk, terminal

When a disk inserted to my cluster, i wanna know that. 
So i need to listen /var/adm/messages and when i catch !NEW! "online" line  i must write it to a different log file.

**When disk goes online I get this kind of log entries:**

```
Dec  8 10:10:46 SMNODE01 genunix: [ID 408114 kern.info] /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000c50095f92a8f (sd69) online
```

Tail works without -F option. But i need -F option :/
**tail messages | grep 408114 | grep '/scsi_vhci/disk@'| egrep -wi --color 'online'**

I have 3 uniform words for grep.
1- The id "408114" is unique for online status.
2- /scsi_vhci/disk@
3- online

P.S: Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `grep` AND use `.*`:

```
$ grep 408114.*/scsi_vhci/disk@.*online test
Dec  8 10:10:46 SMNODE01 genunix: [ID 408114 kern.info] /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000c50095f92a8f (sd69) online
```

Next time don't edit the question completely but ask another question.

Comment: IT WORKS LIKE A CHARM! THANK YOU SO MUCH :)    "tail -F messages | grep 408114.*online"